# My subdomains to a folder won't work

Tags: domains, htaccess

I'm trying to host a WordPress network. Though, the network doesn't work with the built-in WordPress subdomain redirection, that's why I create directly the subdomains at my host (legtux.org, a free French host). The thing is I have a second blog, hosted at thomaskowalski.net/pensees, and I'd like to go there by pensees.thomaskowalski.net. I created a temporary subdomain (http://coucou.thomaskowalski.net/) which should go to the /pensees subfolder, but well... it doesn't (Internal error). Here is my htaccess (at the root) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# uploaded ﬁles
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?ﬁles/(.+) wp-includes/ms-ﬁles.php?ﬁle=$2 [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There must be an option in your host to redirect the pensees folder to your subdomains. Go to sub-domain settings, then instead of redirecting the root folder `/`, try changing the option to this one- `/pensees` or whichever folder you want.